# Saving changes to existing entity with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a notes app that I am trying to model after the Apple Notes app.  I have a NotesTableViewController that displays existing notes and has a button to add new notes.  When the add new notes button is touched, the NoteViewController is pushed onto the stack and the user can type their note.  When the back button is pushed, the saveNote method below is called. This part works fine.  The problem comes when I try to save changes to an existing note.  I select a note from NotesTableViewController, the NoteViewController comes up, I make some changes and push the back button when done.  This just creates a new note instead of updating the existing one.  How do I modify the method below to accomplish this?

```
- (void) saveNote
{
    NSLog(@"Save");
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Note"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:context];

    Note *newManagedObject = 
    [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    if ([textView hasText])
    {
        [newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:self.title forKey:@"noteName"];
        [newManagedObject setValue:textView.text forKey:@"noteText"];
        //NSLog(@"%@", textView.text);
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error 
         appropriately.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working.  Below is the new saveNote method that works.  Also, in the NotesTableViewController's tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I didn't have the managedObject for the NoteViewController set to the selected managedObject.

```
Note *managedNoteObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//  Where detailViewController is an instance of NoteViewController.
detailViewController.managedObject = managedNoteObject;


- (void) saveNote
{
    NSLog(@"Save");

    if([textView hasText])
    {
        [managedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
        NSLog(@"timeStamp: %@", [managedObject valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]);
        [managedObject setValue:self.title forKey:@"noteName"];
        NSLog(@"NoteName: %@", [managedObject valueForKey:@"noteName"]);
        [managedObject setValue:textView.text forKey:@"noteText"];
        NSLog(@"%@", managedObject);
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error 
         appropriately.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```